# Rampant amount of spam being posted as answers

Tags: support, spam

I've run out of my 5 spam flags, the following users are all spammers. I'll add more if more appear.

<strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3513/victoria

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3512/carina

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3511/addie

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3510/tissot

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3509/tankis

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3508/chronos

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3507/gucci

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3506/johnon

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3514/flight

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3516/malcolm

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3517/thomas

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3458/colle

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3519/watch

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3460/icey

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3465/noahr</strike>

Comment: Notice: A similar and probably related incedent has happened at AskUbuntu: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110025/what-can-we-do-about-the-increasing-amount-of-spam-on-ask-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

### Users and their associated sites:

Note that:

- All of these users are unregistered, and therefore do not show up on the [new users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) page.
- They're brand new, so they won't show up in data dump queries such as [baked beans and spam](http://data.stackexchange.com/drupal%20answers/s/1638/seek-and-destroy-spam-spam-urls-spam-baked-beans-and-spam) ([there are several for finding spam](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=spam), you may want to craft your own from these prototypes)

  - note that you need to clone the baked beans and spam query and change this line:

    `where p.n > 2            -- users with at least a few posts`

    to

    `where p.n > 0            -- users with at least a one post`

    if you want to use that query; all these users had one post each.

Here's the list, feel free to add `<strike>`<strike>strike</strike>`</strike` tags or clear the line when these users get destroyed.

- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3513/victoria</strike>

  - glistenshop.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3512/carina</strike>

  - beddingroom.org
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3511/addie</strike>

  - sopgold.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3510/tissot</strike>

  - sopgold.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3509/tankis</strike>

  - cheaprift.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3508/chronos</strike>

  - towholesale.net
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3507/gucci</strike>

  - boyshop.info
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3506/johnon</strike>

  - tomorrowmoon.org
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3514/flight</strike>

  - diablo3goldvip.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3516/malcolm</strike>

  - inbeddingsets.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3517/thomas</strike>

  - appwatches.org
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3458/colle</strike>

  - shopsister.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3519/watch</strike>

  - onbedding.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3460/icey</strike>

  - shopsister.com
- <strike>https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3465/noahr</strike>

  - cheaprift.com

### Sites linked to:

The following links are to `url:*.example.com*` searches on Drupal to find future abuses; not to the site itself.  These are safe to click.  When adding new URLs, be sure to use the same syntax.

These URLs were also listed as the users' website in their profile.

You can't just ctrl-click and open all these in tabs; searching is rate limited to 6 searches in 60 seconds, so do these one-at-a-time:

- [appwatches.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*appwatches.org*+&submit=search)
- [beddingroom.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*beddingroom.org*+&submit=search)
- [boyshop.info](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*boyshop.info*+&submit=search)
- [cheaprift.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*cheaprift.com*+&submit=search)
- [diablo3goldvip.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*diablo3goldvip.com*+&submit=search)
- [glistenshop.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*glistenshop.com*+&submit=search)
- [inbeddingsets.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*inbeddingsets.com*+&submit=search)
- [onbedding.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*onbedding.com*+&submit=search)
- [shopsister.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*shopsister.com*+&submit=search)
- [sopgold.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*sopgold.com*+&submit=search)
- [tomorrowmoon.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*tomorrowmoon.org*+&submit=search)
- [towholesale.net](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*towholesale.net*+&submit=search)

IMO, these are all candidates for a blacklist.

Here's a test for the syntax if the above don't return any results:

- [stackoverflow.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A*stackoverflow.com*+&submit=search)

This last link is *not* a candidate for a blacklist.

If you are a mod, you can find users with these sites in their profile on `/admin/find-users`:

- [appwatches.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=appwatches.org)
- [beddingroom.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=beddingroom.org)
- [boyshop.info](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=boyshop.info)
- [cheaprift.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=cheaprift.com)
- [diablo3goldvip.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=diablo3goldvip.com)
- [glistenshop.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=glistenshop.com)
- [inbeddingsets.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=inbeddingsets.com)
- [onbedding.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=onbedding.com)
- [shopsister.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=shopsister.com)
- [sopgold.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=sopgold.com)
- [tomorrowmoon.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=tomorrowmoon.org)
- [towholesale.net](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=towholesale.net)